# why am I not able to make an image of a folder appear in html? and I get syntax errorr

Tags: html, laravel, model-view-controller

when I try to run this code to fetch an image from a folder I find this error "syntax error, unexpected identifier "assets", expecting ")" but I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `{{url()}}` use `{{asset()}}`.

```html
<img width="250" src="{{asset('assets/images/logo.png')}}" alt="#" />
```

Comment: still not working :(